# Transform the result set into the nested ULs in Jsp

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jstl

I am a beginner in jsp. I can not display a nested resultset in jsp page.
Database: [image: My database]

My sql is below:

```
    select root.name  as root_name
     , down1.name as down1_name
     , down2.name as down2_name
     , down3.name as down3_name
  from categories as root
left outer
  join categories as down1
    on down1.parentid = root.id
left outer
  join categories as down2
    on down2.parentid = down1.id
left outer
  join categories as down3
    on down3.parentid = down2.id
 where root.parentid is null
order 
    by root_name 
     , down1_name 
     , down2_name 
     , down3_name;
```

Output of the above query is in the image link: [image: Query result]

My Bean in Java:

```
 public class Tree {
    private String rootName;
    private String down1Name;
    private String down2Name;
    private String down3Name;
```

My Controller code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/accordion", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getvenuepage(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {

       List<Tree> tree = fmdao.listAlltree();

       //Gson g = new Gson();
       System.out.println("prnt of tree is "+tree);

       model.addObject("tree", tree);
       model.setViewName("sampleaccordion");

       return model; 
   }
```

But all I want is to display the result in proper format on JSP. My Expected output is:

```
animal
   birdie
   doggie
     companion
       chihuahua
       poodle
     herding
       collie
       shepherd
     hunting
       pointer
       setter
       terrier
    gerbil
    horsie
    kittie
mineral
    feldspar
    gypsum
    quartz
    silica
vegetable
    carrot
    celery
    potato
    rutabaga
    tomato
```

Comment: MY suggestion is to do as much processing as possible at the java side.  Maybe create a data structure like a `Map<String, OtherMap>` where the String is your first Dropdown (animal, mineral) etc and then this Other Map is going you be the next level with the string being `birdie` etc and the OtherMap being the next level

Comment: Another hint is for you to use JSTL and also of course you will need to use Javascript to listen for the dropdown/select events